# Intermediate Output of let' s say Resnet50 from Keras Model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

```
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
#2.3.0

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense,TimeDistributed
from keras.models import Model

model = Sequential()
resnet = ResNet50(include_top = False, pooling = 'avg', weights = 'imagenet')
model.add(resnet)

model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

[image: ModelSummary()]

// Training // model.fit( .. ) done

now how to just the output from layer ?

```
model.layers[0]._name='resnet50'
print(model.layers[0].name) # prints resnet50

layer_output = model.get_layer("resnet50").output
intermediate_model = Model(inputs=[model.input, resnet.input], outputs=[layer_output])
result = intermediate_model.predict([x, x])

print(result.shape)
print(result[0].shape)
```

Got Error

> **AttributeError:** Layer resnet50 has multiple inbound nodes, hence the
> notion of "layer output" is ill-defined. Use
> `get_output_at(node_index)` instead. add Codeadd Markdown

[image]

Comment: Which tensorflow version are you using? and what is the shape of `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try again using `tf.keras` to import model and layers.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense,TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

and then run the same:

```
model.layers[0]._name='resnet50'
print(model.layers[0].name) # prints resnet50

layer_output = model.get_layer("resnet50").output
intermediate_model = Model(inputs=[model.input, resnet.input], outputs=[layer_output])

x = tf.ones((1, 250, 250, 3))
result = intermediate_model.predict([x, x])

print(result.shape)
print(result[0].shape)
```

Output:

```
resnet50
(1, 2048)
(2048,)
```

Comment: Thanks.. Could you please throw some light on why the former didnt worked ?

Comment: Sure, Please check [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0) for your reference. Happy Coding!